# Iterate over array of objects and display key and value for each object in ngFor in Angular 12

Tags: html, angular, radio-button, ngfor

In an Angular 12 app the data returned from an API is

```
data = {
  "options":[
     {
       "Yes": 1
     },
     {
       "No": 0
     }
  ]
}
```

My requirement is to iterate over this array and display radio buttons dynamically in the html as shown below.

```
<div *ngFor="let option of data.options;">
  <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="rdgroup" value="{{option.key}}">
  <label>{{option.value}}</label>
</div>
```

I want display labels for radio buttons to be 'Yes' and 'No' and their values should be 1 and 0 respectively. Currently nothing is displayed. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify you data in order to render radio buttons.

Check this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-sidenav-spz9oq?file=app/app.component.html

Use the below method on your component:

```
   options = this.data.options.map( (op) => {
     const key = Object.keys(op)[0];
      return {
        "value" : Object.keys(op)[0],
        "key": op[key]
      }
  });
```

and in template

```
<div *ngFor="let option of options;">
<input type="radio" class="form-control" name="rdgroup" value="{{option.key}}">
<label>{{option.value}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad that I could help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way, It may help you to get expected output!

edit your component.ts file, and add below defined method.

```
getEntrires(object: any) {
    return Object.entries(object);
}
```

this method will return you **Object entry** with it's `KEY` & `VALUE` in Array

For Example:

```
let output = getEntrires({"Yes": 1});
console.log(output) //  [Array[2]] => it will be two dimensional array
```

Now in your html you can consume this in this way

```
<div *ngFor="let option of data.options;">
  <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="rdgroup" value="{{getEntrires(option)[0][1]}}">
  <label>{{getEntrires(option)[0][0]}}</label>
</div>
```